# type signature of Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-signature

```
cow :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
cow x y z = x && y `elem` z

 foo ::
 foo x y z = x `elem` y && y `elem` z

 bar::
 bar x y = case y of
    Nothing -> x
    Just z  -> x + z
```

I don't know what the type signature should be.

Comment: Hint: lookup the signatures of `elem`, `(+)` and `(&&)`.

Comment: may be "elem" is used to find whether x&&y is in the list of Z? I am not very sure, so I used Bool.

Comment: you do not need to know *what* a function is doing in order to determine the types. Signatures can be inferenced, just by looking at the signatures of the functions you use.

Comment: `cow` is also wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In order to determine the type signatures. You do not need to know *what* a function is doing. You can use the type signatures of the functions you use, and do inference on that.

Since the type signature of your `cow` function is not entirely correct, we will show how to derive the type signature of the `cow` function, and then leave the two others as exercises.

We see that `cow` here has three parameters: `x`, `y` and `z`. At the moment, we do not know much about `x`, `y` and `z`. So we will assign a different type variable for these variables. So `x :: a`, `y :: b` and `z :: c`.

Next we can start to derive the types. The function definition of `cow`:

```
cow x y z = x && y `elem` z
```

can be written in a more canonical format as:

```
cow x y z = (&&) x (elem y z)
```

We thus see that we make use of two functions here: [**`(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-38--38-), and [**`elem :: (Eq e, Foldable f) => e -> f e -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem), we here use `e` instead of `f` to avoid "name clashes" with our already defined type variable `a`. Since we use `x` as argument of the `(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` function, we know that `x` should have type `Bool`, and thus that `a ~ Bool` (`a` is the same type as `Bool`). Furthermore we thus know that `(&&) x :: Bool -> Bool`.

Next we see that we call `elem :: (Eq e, Foldable f) => e -> f e -> Bool`. This thus means that `y`, which is the first parameter applied to `elem` thus has type `e`, and therefore `b ~ e`.

It furthermore means that `elem x` thus has type `(Eq e, Foldable f) => f e -> Bool`, and we apply this function to the `z` parameter. This thus means that `c ~ (Eq e, Foldable f) => f e`, and that the type of `elem y z` is `Bool`.

Since the type of `elem y z` is `Bool`, this matches with the function `(&&) x`, and thus the type of `(&&) x (elem y z)` is thus `Bool`.

We thus have derived that:

```
x :: Bool
y :: e
z :: f e
```

with as type constraints `Eq e` and `Foldable f`. This thus means that `cow` has as function:

```
cow :: (Eq e, Foldable f) => Bool -> e -> f e -> Bool
cow x y z = x && y `elem` z
```

Comment: And of course the `Foldable f` may be specialised to `[]`, giving `Bool -> a -> [a] -> Bool`

Comment: @JonPurdy: yes correct. The problem is more with the `x` in the proposed signature in the question.